# Can Leibniz integral rule be extended to differentiation under the sigma sign?

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation

To differentiate $\displaystyle  M(t)=\sum_i e^{tx_i} P(x_i)$ with respect to $t$, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Expand out whatever summation you are working with, i.e. $$\sum\limits_i e^{tx_i}P(x_i)=e^{tx_1}P(x_1)+e^{tx_2}P(x_2)+\cdots$$
Now recall that differentiation is linear and note how the differential operator acts on the rewritten sum:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{tx_1}P(x_1)+e^{tx_2}P(x_2)+\cdots\right)=\frac{d}{dt}e^{tx_1}P(x_1)+\frac{d}{dt}e^{tx_2}P(x_2)+\cdots$$
What can you now say about the derivative of your orignal sum?
$$M'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i}e^{tx_i}P(x_i)=\cdots$$

Comment: I guess my question was whether $ \frac{d}{dt}e^{tx_i}$ makes sense when we have two variables, $t$ and $x_i$. Shouldn't we use partial derivatives instead?

Comment: If $x_i$ is a fixed constant, then it is not necessary to use partial derivatives. If you had a similar function $M(x,t)=e^{tx}$, then $\partial_tM(x,t)=\partial_t e^{tx}$ should be used, but your function above is a function of only one variable.

Comment: @csch2 You cannot exchange summation and differentiation by just argue with a "rewritten sum". This is true for finite sums but in general not for infinite ones as given here. You need some additional conditions on this… (although it works here, but can you explain why?)